# How do I use the modulo function with this library?

Tags: delphi, pascal, biginteger, modulo

I am Using this library for Big Integers in Pascal but I am having trouble using the `modulo` function. Can anyone help?

My code:

```
a = b modulo(c);
```

here is the library location: http://www.delphiforfun.org/programs/library/big_integers.htm

```
{ ***************** Modulo ************* }
procedure TInteger.Modulo(const I2: TInteger);
{ Modulo (remainder after division) - by TInteger }
var
  k: int64;
  imod3: TInteger;
begin
  if high(I2.fDigits) = 0 then begin
    divmodsmall(I2.Sign * I2.fDigits[0], k);
    assignsmall(k);
  end
  else

  begin
    imod3:= GetNextScratchPad;
    DivideRem(I2, imod3);
    Assign(imod3);
    ReleaseScratchPad(imod3);
  end;
end;
```

Why does this not work?:
also why doesnt this work?:

```
var
  P, Q, N, E, D,i: TInteger;
  Eing, Cout: TInteger;

begin
  E := 3;
  D := 27;
  N := 55;
  writeln(N.Modulo(E));
```

Comment: Please [edit] and define *i am having trouble*

Comment: FWIW, @moddersapprentice, if you want fast BigIntegers, try my [BigIntegers.pas](http://www.rvelthuis.de/programs/bigintegers.html) unit. It is a little easier to use and can use operators, e.g. `i3 := i1 mod i2;`. It also has a `DivMod` procedure, returning both quotient and remainder at the same time. My `BigIntegers` are immutable, so they don't "modify themselves" and there is no need to allocate memory, nor do you have to free them. You can use them almost like normal integers.

Answer (score 3):

The source code that you downloaded comes with an example of how to use the modulo function. I urge you to take time to read the example code that comes with a library. If you would do so then you'd be able to solve far more problems by yourself. The example code looks like this:

```
procedure Tbigints.ModBtnClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  i1,i2,i3:Tinteger;
begin
  i1:=TInteger.create(0);
  i2:=TInteger.create(0);
  Getxy(i1,i2);
  i1.modulo(i2);
  memo1.text:=i1.converttoDecimalString(true);
  i1.free;
  i2.free;
  alloclbl.caption:=format('Allocated memory: %d',[allocmemsize]);
end;
```

The key point is that the `modulo` method acts in place. In the code above, the dividend is held in `i1` and the divisor in `i2`. Then you call `modulo` on `i1` passing `i2` as the argument. The result of the operation is then placed in `i1`. So, this method replaces the dividend with the modulus of the division.

Comment: Where did you find this?

Comment: It's in the download from the page you linked to.